# Vectorizing operations using 3d numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working in an algorithm to match two kind of objects (lets say `balls` and `buckets`). Each object is modeled as a 4D numpy array, and each kind is grouped within another array. My method is based on calculating all possible differences between each pair `(ball, bucket)` and applying a similarity function on that difference.

I'm trying to avoid `for` loops since speed is really relevant for what I'm doing, so I'm creating those differences by reshaping one of the initial arrays, broadcasting numpy operations and creating a 3D numpy array (`diff_map`). I'm not finding any good tutorial about this, so I'd like to know if there is a more "proper way" to do that. Id also like to see any good references about this kind of operation (multidimensional reshape and broadcast) if possible.

My code:

```
import numpy as np

balls = np.random.rand(3,4)
buckets = np.random.rand(6,4)
buckets = buckets.reshape(len(buckets), 1, 4)
buckets
array([[[ 0.38382622,  0.27114067,  0.63856317,  0.51360638]],

   [[ 0.08709269,  0.21659216,  0.31148519,  0.99143705]],

   [[ 0.03659845,  0.78305241,  0.87699971,  0.78447545]],

   [[ 0.11652137,  0.49490129,  0.76382286,  0.90313785]],

   [[ 0.62681395,  0.10125169,  0.61131263,  0.15643676]],

   [[ 0.97072113,  0.56535597,  0.39471204,  0.24798229]]])

diff_map = balls-buckets
diff_map.shape
(6, 3, 4)
```

**For Loop**

As requested, this is the `for` loop I'm trying to avoid:

```
diff_map_for = np.zeros((len(buckets), len(balls), 4))
for i in range(len(buckets)):
    for j in range(len(balls)):
        diff_map_for[i, j] = buckets[i]-balls[j]
```

`Just to be sure, let's compare the two results:

```
np.all(diff_map == diff_map_for)
True
```

Comment: Share your loopy code? We know you are trying to avoid that, but it would be easier to understand what you want looking at your loopy code.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have you looked at the doc? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: So, what exactly is the question again? Are you asking why that reshaped version : `balls-buckets` works? Look into broadcasting docs, as mentioned earlier as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
import numpy as np

balls = np.random.rand(3,4)
buckets = np.random.rand(6,4)

diff_map = buckets[:, np.newaxis, :] - balls[np.newaxis, :, :]
print(diff_map.shape)
# output: (6, 3, 4)

# ... compared to for loop
diff_map_for = np.zeros((len(buckets), len(balls), 4))
for i in range(len(buckets)):
    for j in range(len(balls)):
        diff_map_for[i, j] = buckets[i] - balls[j]

print(np.sum(diff_map - diff_map_for))
# output: 0.0
```

Comment: Right in the spot. I'm not familiar with this `np.newaxis` but it solved the problem and is great for readability! Thanks!